# Wald test for sum of coefficients in R

Tags: r, stata, wald-test

I am "translating" code from STATA to R, and need to translate the following command:

```
.regress lq lland lseed llabor
.test _b[lland]+_b[lseed]+_b[llabor]=1
```

Which runs a Wald test on the hypothesis that the sum of the three coefficients of the OLS model (shown above) is equal to one.

For the R code, I am currently working with the "Wald_test" command from the "clubSandwich" package, which seems to be adept in testing the equality of coefficients, but not the equality of their sum to an integer. Is there a way to do this, or am I approaching the problem in the wrong way?

Comment: Let your variables be $x_1,x_2,x_3$ with response $y.$ Your model $y=\beta_1x_1+\beta_2x_2+\beta_3x_3$ is equivalent to $y-x_1=\alpha_1 x_1 + \alpha_2(x_2-x_1) + \alpha_3(x_3-x_1)$ and, by comparing coefficients, you can check that $\beta_1+\beta_2+\beta_3-1=\alpha_1.$ Thus, when you fit the second model, the software automatically tests the hypothesis $\alpha_1=0,$ which is precisely what you want!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `linearHypothesis()` function in package `car` is probably the most convenient function for this. With your data you can do something like this:

```
library("car")
m <- lm(lq ~ lland + lseed + llabor, ...)
linearHypothesis(m, "lland + lseed + llabor = 1")
```

See also the *Further inference and nested model comparisons* item in the *Econometrics* task view at https://CRAN.R-project.org/view=Econometrics.